# Algebraic notation of my longitudinal mixed effects model

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, notation

I have fit two models in R using the NLME package. The first one includes time varying variables and the second one time invariant variables.

Model 1:
Y ~ Time_measured, random = ~ Time_Measured|ID

Model 2:
Y ~ Time_measured + Baseline_Y*Minutes, random =~Time_Measured|ID

How can I rewrite these models using an algebraic notation?

Comment: You can write them both using the general equation for mixed models: **$Y = X\beta + Zu + \epsilon$**. Is there any reason why you use `nlme` and not a more up-to-date package ?

Comment: @RobertLong Thanks for that! I decided to go against using notation when writing-up my results as I feel that it might confuse the reader and to save some space. There is no particular reason, I ran the same models using the 'lmer' package (lme4) and got similar estimates, Std errors and random effects so I decided to use 'nlme'.